# match color of brighter area to the darker within the same image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to match the dark area on the bottom right of my image to the bright area on the top left. I have tried equalizing and working with levels to no avail. Thanks

Comment: can you post the image because details may differ, and this will be easy to understand for everyone

Comment: Actually you won't be able to add an image (I think) but a link will allow someone else to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understand the question correctly but I will give it a try.

I assume that your image has a diagonal brightness inequality, from top-left to bottom-right.

Depending on how uniform this inequality is, you can try the following technique:

1. Create a new layer.
2. Setup the new layer as 'Multiply' for the
   blending option.
3. Use the gradient tool to create a gradient that
   covers the whole image, goes from white to black, and follows the
   brightness inequality of the image.
4. Adjust the opacity so it
   matches your image.
5. Use the transform tool on the new layer to
   further refine your brightness correction.
6. Try white-to-grey
   instead of white-to-black to further refine your correction.

Alternative solution:

1. Follow steps 1. to 3. from earlier solution.
2. Use this new layer as a mask for a brightness adjustment layer.

If these don't answer your question, please clarify it.